# How to check if the libraries in my project are compatible with IE?

Tags: angular, internet-explorer-11, libraries, compatibility

at the begining of my new project it worked perfectly in ie 11.9 but when I add the libraries and/or my code it stop working in IE (other browsers work), is there any way to check the compatibility of the libraries with IE?

```
    "@angular/animations": "^9.1.9",
    "@angular/cdk": "9.2.4",
    "@angular/common": "^9.1.4",
    "@angular/compiler": "9.1.9",
    "@angular/core": "^9.1.4",
    "@angular/forms": "^9.1.4",
    "@angular/material": "^9.2.4",
    "@angular/material-moment-adapter": "^9.2.4",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^9.1.4",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^9.1.9",
    "@angular/router": "^9.1.4",
    "classlist.js": "^1.1.20150312",
    "jquery": "1.9.1 - 3",
    "ng2-pdf-viewer": "^6.3.0",
    "popper.js": "^1.16.0",
    "rxjs": "^6.5.5",
    "tslib": "^1.11.1",
    "web-animations-js": "^2.3.2",
    "zone.js": "^0.10.3"
```

Regards

Comment: I am fairly sure now that ng2-pdf-viewer is not compatible with IE but haven't found confirmation yet.

Comment: You need to check after adding which library your code gets stopped working in IE? Check whether any polyfills are needed to use those packages for the IE browser. Try to apply those polyfills may help to fix this issue. If there is a need to transpile some code then you can use Babel.js library.

Answer (score 2):

I guess there is no command in angular to check browser compatibility for libraries. You can go and check Browser Support if libraries has mentioned on their README.md file.

Answer (score 0):

Developer console in IE should be showing the error message. This error message will have a clue about which JavaScript file (or package) is not working fine.